# Connection refused error in curl while calling mandrill api

Tags: post, curl, connection, mandrill

To send transactional email using mandrill api, I am using this mandrill api -

```
https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json
```

And I am trying to post this JSON data (payload) to it -

```
{
'key' : 'MyActualKey',
'message': {
    'html': '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
    'text': 'Example text content',
    'subject': 'example subject',
    'from_email': 'from@example.com',
    'from_name': 'Test',
    'to': [
        {
            'email': 'to@example.com',
            'name': 'Hussain',
            'type': 'to'
        }
    ],
    'headers': {
        'Reply-To': 'reply@example.com'
    },
    'merge': True,
    'tags': [
        'Mandrill Test'
    ]
 },
'ip_pool': 'Main Pool'
}
```

So when I execute this curl command -

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @TestMandrillPayload.json https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json -v
```

I get this error -

```
* About to connect() to proxy 127.0.0.1 port 8000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

But when I use the same json here -

```
https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method-send
```

the email get sent successfully.

I tried searching for the cause of this issue on internet, Everybody suggests that there is something wrong with my DNS or with my firewall. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If its the DNS issue then ping the domain `mandrillapp.com` and get the IP and use it on your curl.

If you have different DNS servers IP address then you can specify it with your curl command as well.

```
--dns-servers IP
```

Also, use the `-k` commandline parameter with the curl command.

Comment: Actually somehow `HTTP_PROXY` variable was set to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. I unset that var and it works now.